# git log -all shows commits removed with filter-branch

Tags: git

To remove everything that is not "my_dir/" in my repository history I used:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter my_dir/  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d;
git reflog expire --expire=now --all;
git gc --prune=now;
```

Now, using:

```
git log
```

everything seems fine: the log only shows commits containing files in "my_dir".

But:

```
git log --all
```

still shows everything. In fact, doing another filter-branch (to remove some other .pyc files in my_dir) will find (and remove) all the .pyc files in the old dirs.

It seems that --subdirectory-filter doesn't really remove the commits... they are still there.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

subdirectory-filter "only look at the history which touches the given subdirectory". So maybe it doesn't remove all the other commits, but just rewrites the ones that touch that dir and somehow leaves "orphans" for the others???

Comment: re your edit: `--subdirectory-filter` only adds rewritten commits for commits that touch that directory; but if a ref has any such commits in its history, then that ref gets rewritten.  So this could be the issue, IF you have refs (could be branch or tag) that cannot reach any commit that ever touched the subdirectory

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger's comment here is probably the really-right answer. Note that `--all` means "all refs in `refs/`, plus HEAD itself".

Answer (score 2):

The `filter-branch` command creates new refs to the "old" commits in case you need to undo.  `git log --all` shows the history of *all* refs, including the special refs that `filter-branch` created.

More generally, the only git command (I can think of) that will actually delete a commit object is `gc`.  For `gc` to remove a commit, it must not be reachable from any ref or from the reflog.  So if you want the commits to be really gone:

1) Delete the `original/*` refs

2) Wipe out the reflog

3) run an aggressive gc with `prune=now`

Comment: as you can see from my question I did  reflog expire +  gc --prune=now, and  the commits are still there...

Comment: as you can see from my answer that won't work until you also remove the "backup" refs that filter-branch created

Comment: The commits may be removed only if they not lay in commits chain handled by one or more branch. You need to find which branch hold that chain with that commit.

Comment: @oklas - Which ref, not which branch.  And the ref that we *know* holds the commit is the backup ref created by `filter-branch`.  Until that's deleted and `gc` still fails to prune the commit, there's no reason to go searching for anything else.

Comment: did rm -rf .git/refs/original/, still same problem (+ git reflog expire --expire=now --all; git gc --prune=now;)

Comment: You may need to expire the reflog again (after making sure all original refs are gone), or just rm .git/logs; but if that doesn't work, the next step would be `git for-each-ref --contains <sha1>` where `<sha1>` is the commit ID of one of the commits that ought to be deleted.  This will list any refs that are still holding the commit from being deleted, and you can deal with them.

Comment: Also note that you may want to add `--aggressive` to your `gc` command

Comment: Once you've run `git gc`, the `refs/original/` references become "packed" and must be deleted with `git update-ref -d` or (easier but a bit cheat-y) by editing `.git/packed-refs`. On the other hand, the original `git for-each-ref` should have done that by this point.